# How to use Bokeh BoxSelect tool?

Tags: callback, selection, bokeh

I'm trying to use the BoxSelect tool but my callback does not get invoked. This is what I tried, based on snippets I found on the net.

```
from bokeh.models.sources import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.plotting import figure, curdoc

x = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
y = [i*i for i in x]
source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x=x,y=y))
p = figure(tools="xbox_select")
p.line("x", "y", source=source)

def selectedCallback(attr, old, new):
    print("Selected callback")

source.on_change('selected', selectedCallback)

curdoc().add_root(p)
```

The selection box does show when dragging the mouse but the callback is not called.

(using Bokeh 0.11.1 and Python 3.5.1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so I found the answer: it seems that line plots do not support selection. Changing the `p.line` into `p.scatter` makes it work. In my real app I add invisible scatter points to the line so that selection works. This is a workaround but it gets me going.